# Pytorch custom CUDA extension build fails for torch 1.6.0 or higher

Tags: c++, cuda, pytorch, torch

I have a custom CUDA extension for pytorch (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_extension.html), which used to work fine with pytorch1.4, CUDA10.1, and Titan Xp GPUs. However, recently we changed our system to new A40 GPUs and CUDA11.1. When I try to build my custom pytorch extension using CUDA11.1, pytorch 1.8.1, gcc 9.3.0, and Ubuntu 20.04 I get the following errors:

```
$ python3 setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating cuda_test.egg-info
writing cuda_test.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to cuda_test.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to cuda_test.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'cuda_test.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'cuda_test.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'cuda_test.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_ext
building 'cuda_test' extension
creating /path/to/code/cuda/test/build
creating /path/to/code/cuda/test/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
Emitting ninja build file /path/to/code/cuda/test/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/build.ninja...
Compiling objects...
Allowing ninja to set a default number of workers... (overridable by setting the environment variable MAX_JOBS=N)
[1/1] /cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/bin/nvcc --generate-dependencies-with-compile --dependency-output /path/to/code/cuda/test/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/test_cuda.o.d -I/path/to/code/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include -I/path/to/code/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/path/to/code/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/path/to/code/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/include -I/path/to/code/venv/include/python3.7m -c -c /path/to/code/cuda/test/test_cuda.cu -o /path/to/code/cuda/test/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/test_cuda.o -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_BFLOAT16_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ --expt-relaxed-constexpr --compiler-options ''"'"'-fPIC'"'"'' -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H '-DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE="_gcc"' '-DPYBIND11_STDLIB="_libstdcpp"' '-DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI="_cxxabi1011"' -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=cuda_test -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -gencode=arch=compute_86,code=compute_86 -gencode=arch=compute_86,code=sm_86 -std=c++14
FAILED: /path/to/code/cuda/test/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/test_cuda.o
/cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/bin/nvcc --generate-dependencies-with-compile --dependency-output /path/to/code/cuda/test/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/test_cuda.o.d -I/path/to/code/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include -I/path/to/code/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/path/to/code/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/path/to/code/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/include -I/path/to/code/venv/include/python3.7m -c -c /path/to/code/cuda/test/test_cuda.cu -o /path/to/code/cuda/test/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/test_cuda.o -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_BFLOAT16_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ --expt-relaxed-constexpr --compiler-options ''"'"'-fPIC'"'"'' -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H '-DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE="_gcc"' '-DPYBIND11_STDLIB="_libstdcpp"' '-DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI="_cxxabi1011"' -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=cuda_test -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -gencode=arch=compute_86,code=compute_86 -gencode=arch=compute_86,code=sm_86 -std=c++14
/cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/include/thrust/detail/complex/arithmetic.h(256): error: identifier "FLT_MIN" is undefined

/cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/include/thrust/detail/complex/arithmetic.h(274): error: identifier "DBL_MIN" is undefined

/cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/include/thrust/detail/complex/catrig.h(190): error: identifier "DBL_EPSILON" is undefined

/cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/include/thrust/detail/complex/catrig.h(228): error: identifier "DBL_EPSILON" is undefined

/cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/include/thrust/detail/complex/catrig.h(243): error: identifier "DBL_EPSILON" is undefined

/cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/include/thrust/detail/complex/catrig.h(293): error: identifier "DBL_EPSILON" is undefined

/cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/include/thrust/detail/complex/catrig.h(406): error: identifier "DBL_EPSILON" is undefined

/cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/include/thrust/detail/complex/catrig.h(498): error: identifier "DBL_MAX" is undefined

/cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/include/thrust/detail/complex/catrig.h(562): error: identifier "DBL_MAX_EXP" is undefined

/cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/include/thrust/detail/complex/catrig.h(565): error: identifier "DBL_MANT_DIG" is undefined

/cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/include/thrust/detail/complex/catrig.h(630): error: identifier "DBL_EPSILON" is undefined

/cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/include/thrust/detail/complex/catrigf.h(119): error: identifier "FLT_EPSILON" is undefined

/cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/include/thrust/detail/complex/catrigf.h(137): error: identifier "FLT_EPSILON" is undefined

/cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/include/thrust/detail/complex/catrigf.h(147): error: identifier "FLT_EPSILON" is undefined

/cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/include/thrust/detail/complex/catrigf.h(170): error: identifier "FLT_EPSILON" is undefined

/cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/include/thrust/detail/complex/catrigf.h(249): error: identifier "FLT_EPSILON" is undefined

/cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/include/thrust/detail/complex/catrigf.h(327): error: identifier "FLT_MAX" is undefined

/cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/include/thrust/detail/complex/catrigf.h(375): error: identifier "FLT_MAX_EXP" is undefined

/cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/include/thrust/detail/complex/catrigf.h(377): error: identifier "FLT_MANT_DIG" is undefined

/cm/shared/apps/cuda11.1/toolkit/11.1.1/include/thrust/detail/complex/catrigf.h(420): error: identifier "FLT_EPSILON" is undefined
```

I also wrote a simple test code to verify that my larger CPP/CUDA code isn't the culprit, which produced the same error messages. I also checked if arithmetic.h and catrig.h include <cfloat>, which should provide the {FLT,DBL}_{MIN,MAX,EPSILON,MANT_DIG} definitions but this looks all normal, since it's standard NVIDIA code.
Let me know if anyone has encountered a similar problem or would know a solution.

---- UPDATE ----

Here are a couple of more things that I've tried:

1. The CUDA code compiles when I use CUDA10.1, pytorch 1.4.0, gcc 9.3.0, and Ubuntu 20.04.
2. Using pytorch 1.5.1 instead generates the following error:
   `/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_function.h(437): error: identifier "__builtin_is_constant_evaluated" is undefined`
   but this can be solved by downgrading gcc to version 7.5.
3. Using pytorch 1.6.0 or higher instead always results in the errors reported in the beginning, even when using gcc-7.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48-hour delay before doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The Intel MKL module wasn't loaded properly and caused the error. After fixing this the compilation worked just fine also with CUDA 11.1 and pytorch 1.8.1!